# Java polymorphism and method chaining

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

So I have a couple of inherited classes defined like so.

```
class Base {
    public Base chainedMethodA() {
        // some stuff
        return this;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public Derived chainedMethodB() {
        // some stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, the following code works:

```
Derived obj = new Derived();
obj.chainedMethodB().chainedMethodA();
```

But this does not (notice the switched order of function calls):

```
Derived obj = new Derived();
obj.chainedMethodA().chainedMethodB();
```

The compiler gives an error on the `chainedMethodB()` function call. I can understand that this is because when you run `chainedMethodA()`, it returns an object of type `Base`, which does not have `chainedMethodB` defined.

I can think of a few solutions to this problem:

1. Chain methods while paying attention to order (call `Derived`'s methods first, and then call `Base`'s methods). This looks like a very brittle solution.
2. Override `chainedMethodA` in `Derived` so it returns an instance of `Derived` instead of `Base`. This looks like a waste of inheritance.

Is there any elegant way around this problem? Maybe some construct that magically changes `chainedMethodA` to return a `Derived` instance when called by an object of type `Derived`, without being explicitly overridden in `Derived`.

Comment: 2 isn't a waste of inheritance. It is what inheritance is: override to do something more specific, in this case: return a more specific type.

Comment: @TI Sure it will: you can override and declare to return a more specific type. With `@Override public Derived chainedMethodA() { ... }`

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want `Derived`'s `chainedMethodA` to return an instance of `Derived` then it can't call the super implementation anyway (because that might return an actual `Base` which isn't a `Derived`).  So you're not losing anything that way, and you allow `Derived` objects to still be used as `Base`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Override `chainedMethodA` in `Derived` so it returns an instance of
>   `Derived` instead of Base. This looks like a waste of inheritance.

**You're wrong. You aren't wasting inheritance.**

Technique of overriding is to do just that namely specialize a method. Override can be done when the returned type is the same or a subtype of the return type declared in the original overridden method in the superclass. So in this case you are violating nothing.

Read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm) for more about overriding.

Here example 1: (calling the superclass method)

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public Derived chainedMethodA(){

         super.chainedMethodA();
         //some stuff
        return this;
    }

    public Derived chainedMethodB() {
        // some stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```

Here example 2: (changing it completele)

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public Derived chainedMethodA(){
        //some stuff
        return this;
    }

    public Derived chainedMethodB() {
        // some stuff
        return this;
    }
    }
```

Comment: IMO, your answer could use of an example of such overriding :).

Comment: Thanks for editing! I'm not so sure about `return (Derived) super.chainedMethodA();`. `chainedMethodA` could return a `Base` and this would fail (`ClassCastException`). How about `super.chainedMethodA(); return this;`?

Comment: @Tunaki yeah mixed solitution obviusly working. But when could return a Base? If the chainMethodA is called by Derived class.. this is an instance of Derived. Isn't?

Comment: Imagine `chainedMethodA()` returns for some reason `new Base()` :). (it would defeat the name I agree but it isn't strictly forbidden).

Comment: Ahahahah yeah i was refering to this example. However i'll edit to be more generic

Answer (score 0):

In this situation inheritance is probably the simplest solution.

However, your last sentence pretty much explains generics:

> Maybe some construct that magically changes chainedMethodA to return a
>   Derived instance when called by an object of type Derived, without
>   being explicitly overridden in Derived.

So something like this may be useful in other similar use cases:

```
static class Base {
    public <T extends Base> T chainedMethodA(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        // some stuff
        return clazz.cast(this);
    }
}

static class Derived extends Base {
    public Derived chainedMethodB() {
        // some stuff
        return this;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Derived obj = new Derived();
    obj.chainedMethodA(Derived.class).chainedMethodB();
}
```

Comment: No. This is overkill. Do you really think introducing the Reflection API is aboslutely necessary here? Plus,  it does not do what the OP wants since it _creates_ a new instance.

Comment: OP was more worried about return types so I didn't pay attention to what the method was actually doing. Nevertheless, Ive updated so it returns the same instance. (and I agree its probably overkill in the op situation, hence the first line)